# Single word or phrase for the irony of helping someone while they are taking advantage of you

Tags: phrases

While Bob was masking Linda's mistakes, Linda was informing everyone that Bob was not qualified for his position.
example; "Have you ever found yourself in a(an)________situation"

Comment: You've described what's happening. Please add another sentence showing how your single word or phrase would actually be used. Different words may emphasize different points of view; perhaps describing Bob's position or what Linda was doing. We need to know exactly what you want.

Comment: The disparity of answers given so far only emphasises the omission.

Comment: Particularly important is whether the word/phrase should describe the situation from the point of view of the good person (the patsy, the innocent, the gullible) or the bad one (the wolf in sheep's clothing, the snake in the grass...).

Answer (score 2):

**'Bite the hand that feeds you'**

applies here, though it applies to the actions of the wrongdoer rather than the benefactor.

> *bite the hand that feeds you*: to act badly towards the person who is helping or has helped you

[[CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bite-the-hand-that-feeds-you)]

Comment: Not really. As you say, this phrase would answer better the question '*Single word or phrase for the irony of **having someone take advantage of you while you are helping them***.

Comment: @Dan It's the same irony, but viewed from a different perspective.